# How to read/write data via socket from the client in qt6 C++?

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, communication, qt6

below given is my C++ QT6 code:

```
    QTcpServer funcServer;
    if (!(funcServer.listen(QHostAddress::AnyIPv4, 8011))) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to start the server.";
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Server started on port" << funcServer.serverPort() << " with it's address = "<< funcServer.serverAddress();
    }
    
    // Wait for a client to connect
    if (funcServer.waitForNewConnection(-1)) {
        QTcpSocket* funcClientSocket = funcServer.nextPendingConnection();
        qDebug() << "A client is connected.";
        this->isConnected = true;
        // Process the client connection
        while(true){
            qDebug() << "Trying to receive:";
            QByteArray data = funcClientSocket->read(1024);
            qDebug() << "Received data:" << data;
            QThread::sleep(0.1);
        }}
```

I tried using python for it and it works fine below given is my python code

```py
import socket
listensocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listensocket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 8011))
#* Starts server
listensocket.listen(999)
print("Server started at " + socket.gethostname() + " on port " + str(8011))
#* Accepts the incoming connection
(clientsocket, address) = listensocket.accept()
print(f"New connection made! at address = {address}")
while True:
    message = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()  # * Gets the incoming message
    print(message)
```

> NOTE: Data is coming from a raspberry pi python program and both sender an receiver are connected to the same Network(Wi-Fi)

actually the C++ code prints the following thing

```bash
Trying to recive:
Received data: ""
Trying to recive:
Received data: ""
Trying to recive:
Received data: ""
```

Comment: I don't know about QT but usually in sockets, receiving "" means the other end closed the connection

Comment: If so can you tell me that why would other end closes the connection after the connection is been made and it is sending the data, the only problem is that somehow the receiver can't read it.

Comment: From the [documentation for `QIODevice::read`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#read-1): `"This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty QByteArray can mean either that no data was currently available for reading, or that an error occurred"`.  If you want to know when data becomes available connect to the [`readyRead` signal](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readyRead).

Comment: AFAIK `QIODevice::read` is none blocking. So if receive buffer is empty it will return immediately empty `QByteArray` as a result you are flooded with logs about no data (and probably you missed logs if data are received). You should use signal slots to make this code idiomatic for Qt! Or at least add [QIODevice::waitForReadyRead](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#waitForReadyRead) to your code.